# how to change the day output from 2 days to lets say 50 days

Tags: macbook-pro

I read this:
[See website visit time in Safari history](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235357/see-website-visit-time-in-safari-history?newreg=40c287489f824485ba9da314c36877af)

In this article, there is something like this

```
 sqlite3 ~/Library/Safari/History.db 'select visit_time,title from history_visits order by visit_time desc;' \
     | while read i; do d="${i%%.*}"; echo "$(date -r $((d+978307200))) | ${i#*|}"; done \
     | head -n 30
```

My question:
how could I extend this script from 2 days to 50 days
thanks for answering

Comment: thanks I only see "normal Windows" in terminal. is it possible to show the adresses from "private windows" ? (normal window: I don't know if this is a correct word)

Comment: Please don't post comments as answers :-)

Comment: The idea of private mode is to leave as few traces as possible. This means that pages visited in private mode won't show up in the history.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the one-liner which limits by days. If you want to see *all* visited pages, remove the trailing `\  | head -n 30` (which currently cuts off the output after 30 lines).

If you still don't see more than two days, check the history settings in Safari.

Comment: thanks
if I do this like you mentioned
'''
sqlite3 ~/Library/Safari/History.db 'select visit_time,title from history_visits order by visit_time desc;' \
> | while read i; do d="${i%%.*}"; echo "$(date -r $((d+978307200))) | ${i#*|}"; done \
> '''
there is no difference in terminal output

Comment: @renitent The query can't show more lines than there are in the history :-)

Comment: thanks                                                                                                                     I only see "normal Windows". is it possible to show the adresses from "private windows" ? (normal window: I don't know if this is a correct word)