# How to access / export Safari browsing as file

Tags: macos, safari, browser-history

How can I export my Safari browsing history?

Alternatively, where does Safari store the history data?

(Yes, of course, I can click history in the menu bar, but that interface isn't very *useful*.)

Answer (score 1):

The browsing history is located in a database stored at `~/Library/Safari/History.db`.<sup>[1](https://eshop.macsales.com/blog/45194-tech-tip-recovering-deleted-safari-browsing-history-on-a-mac/comment-page-1/?unapproved=162526&moderation-hash=0497d36d0e1533e8f2c7d3d20d24f18c#comment-162526)</sup>

This database can be accessed with sqlite3 via Terminal<sup>[2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/313670/154137)</sup>:

```
sqlite3 ~/Library/Safari/History.db
```

At least on my device, the database has the following tables:

```
sqlite> SELECT name FROM sqlite_schema WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name;
history_client_versions
history_event_listeners
history_events
history_items
history_items_to_tags
history_tags
history_tombstones
history_visits
metadata
sqlite_sequence
```