# 1991 timestamp in safari history

Tags: safari, browser-history

I just opened my Safari History.db and realised that there are timestamps like

671015068.337777

which don't make sense, as I started to use my laptop this year...

any idea ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok,

there is apparently 978307200 missing

got it from
[See website visit time in Safari history](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235357/see-website-visit-time-in-safari-history)

(although, don't know why)